# How do I find what I have left to do?

Tags: just-cause-2

There are handy numbers showing you the completion percentage for each area in Just Cause 2, but how do I find what I have left to do? I have several areas stuck at just over 90% because I can't track down the last 1-2 things to do.

I know the collectibles can be found with the radar signal but if it's a large area it can occasionally be hard to find them. The destructible stuff on the the other hand is *usually* obvious but can sometimes be hidden away behind trees, etc.

Is there a way for me to:

- find out *what* I have left to complete for an area, and/or
- find out *where* in an area these things are.

Some sort of map upgrade, perchance?

**Edit:** Prompted by comments - I am playing on PC so if this is only possible through mods, I'm happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: I hope you're playing on PC; [100% is impossible in an unmodified game](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Just_Cause_2_100%25_completion_list)

Comment: Thank goodness there isn't a 100% achievement associated with this.

Comment: @deutschZuid yes, that would be an outrage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're playing on PC, you can use the [JC2 Map Viewer](http://www.justcause2mods.com/mods/other/Miscellaneous/JC2-Map-Viewer-%28Updated%29/) to see the locations of uncollected crates and undestroyed chaos objects. Several crates are missing from the game, and will be marked so in the tooltip when moused over in the program - you will need to download the [100% completion mod](http://www.justcause2mods.com/mods/other/Miscellaneous/100-percent-completion/) if you wish to collect these crates and 100% the game.

[image: jc2 map viewer]

Comment: Although other answers were helpful by pointing out the 100% mods, this one is more directly relevant as it answers the question of "how do I see what's left?"

Comment: Hells, this would have been handy when I was doing my run through!

Answer (score 4):

Just Cause 2 cannot be completed to 100% because there are a few missing collectibles. The modding community has fixed this however; you can find the mod [here](http://www.justcause2mods.com/component/content/article/1-front-page-news/65-100-completion-now-possible-with-new-mod.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to see where the last items in any given area are, you have to just move about and hope you spot a destructible or a pickup on the radar.  There's no compass type thing to show you.

When I was playing through I'd use a checklist like [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/943499-just-cause-2/62802715) to work out what I'd missed.